# Como saber la fecha en la que expira un token desde el frontend?

Tags: javascript, angular, jwt

En mi frontend recibo un JWT token, que viene con una estrucutura parecida eyXXXXXX.eyXXXXXXXX.2JXXXXXX , cuando pongo ese token en la pagina jwt.io puedo ver su fecha de expiracion pero se puede saber la fecha de expiracion desde el frontend?, es decir con el codigo, alguna funcion que yo le pase ese codigo largo y me devuelva la fecha de expiración.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Lo mejor es hacer esa validación en el backend. El tratamiento del token en el frontend puede abrir huecos de seguridad.

Comment: Algo -poco- burdo es sumarle a la fecha (y hora) en que recibes el token el número de segundo expresados en `expires_in`.

Answer (score 1):

Como mencionas, en jwt.io puedes ver el decode de tu token.

Si requieres hacer el decode desde Angular, puedes apoyarte en alguna dependencia como [angular-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt).

```
import { JwtHelperService } from "@auth0/angular-jwt";

const helper = new JwtHelperService();

const decodedToken = helper.decodeToken(myRawToken);
const expirationDate = helper.getTokenExpirationDate(myRawToken);
const isExpired = helper.isTokenExpired(myRawToken);
```

Por otro lado, si necesitas, puedes convertir el string en una fecha:

```
const expDate = Date(dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

No es lo mas recomendado de hacer, pero en caso de contar con la fecha de expiración en tu token, lo podrías decodificar y mirar si la fecha de expiración es menor a la fecha actual, acá un fragmento de código de ejemplo

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/token+expired+check+js